# jQueryUI or BlockUI modal dialog over PART of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, blockui

I want to have a modal dialog over part of a web page, just a div container. I know a bespoke solution is likely the answer but I'm wondering if BlockUI can apply it's modal overlay to a specific div **only**.

Google/stackoverflow has bared no fruit when asking if this is possible with jQueryUI or BlockUI.

Is modifying an existing overlay solution the only answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a div with the particular dimensions and position, and then block that.

#### JS

```
$('body').append('<div id="blocker"></div>');
$('#blocker').block({message: null});
```

#### CSS

```
#blocker {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    height: 75px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

[Demo →](http://jsbin.com/asele4/)

Comment: Thank you! I think my knowledge of BlockUI was a little lacking. This helped

Comment: @Charlie: You're welcome. Sorry for the jsbin link; I prefer jsfiddle but it was having issues with the BlockUI plugin.